# create an exponential function that creates a graph from xy(1,1) to (0,0)

Tags: matlab, math, exponential

I am trying to create a graph where two points of x,y are predefined (1,1 and 0,0) but values decrease exponentially between these values. I've looked into using y=2^x type stuff but that gives me a y intercept of 1 when i want it to be 0. Can anyone shed some light?
Thanks in advance

Comment: For the points you give, the function must be *increasing* between 0 and 1, not *decreasing*. So you want the function to *increase exponentially* between those two values.

Comment: Why is 2^x your assumed function?  I think a simple power law, shown below, is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You want a function of the form

[image]

Apply the boundary conditions and you have a pair of simultaneous equations:

[image]

Solve these and you have:

[image]

Therefore the functional form you want is:

[image]

Where `b` can be any positive value (except 1). Note that you want `b > 1` for functions with increasing gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You can fit any number of points, including the two you have.

If you assume `y = a*x^b` is the form you need, then you can take the log of both sides:

```
log(y) = log(a*x^b) = log(a) + b*log(x)
```

This is a classic linear relationship between `(log(x), log(y))`.  You can use any least squares fit method you wish to solve for the constants `log(a)` and `b`.

Just one caveat: The assumed function *requires* `(x,y) = (0,0)`, but you can't include that point in the fit, since `lim log(x) = -infinity` as `x` approaches zero.

If `(x,y) = (1,1)`, then `1 = a*1^b = a`.  Your two boundary conditions are satisfied by `y = x^b`, where `b` is a value of your choosing `(b > 0)`.  If `b = 1`, then you have a straight line from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)`.  Higher positive values of `b` will start off flatter and rise faster.  Pick a value that matches your needs.

If you have more than two points you'll calculate the constants using least squares fit.

Once you have them, it's easy to go back to `(x, y)` space.